# SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect (but not all the time)

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2012, php, connectivity, web-server

I have a CentOS6 webserver and a database server (MS SQL Server 2012). When I use the website everything is going fine except that once an hour or so I get a can't connect error in my php code. I looked in the ssl_error_log and found the following error at the same time I got the error:

```
PHP Warning:  odbc_connect(): SQL error: [unixODBC][FreeTDS][SQL Server]Unable to connect to data source, SQL state S1000 in SQLConnect
```

Can anyone help me solve this strange problem?
I'm not sure if it's a problem with the sql server or the webserver. I can't find any problems in the event viewer on the sql server.

Comment: does the sql server error log have some messages for the moments when it is "offline"

Comment: can't realy find anything in the error_log. but thanks for the tip, i found out i get connection has been closed messages when alient vault scans the sql server.

Comment: there you go, it is the antivirus :)  Check this out: https://www.brentozar.com/archive/2014/05/configure-anti-virus-sql-servers/

Comment: alientvault isn't an antivirus program but checks for security vulnerabilities in applications across the network. but disabled scanning of the sql server. see if it helps. if it still persist then i will come back to you :)